# pam_acct_mgmt seg faulting when Max Num of Days is < Num days of warning before expiration

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, pam

I am writing a very simple PAM authentication function shown below.

```
 int authenticate(char* user, char* pass)
 {
    int value = pam_start("passwd", user, &conv, &pamh);
    if (value == PAM_SUCCESS)
    {
       reply = (struct pam_response*)malloc(sizeof(struct pam_response));
       reply[0].resp = pass;
       reply[0].resp_retcode = 0;
       value = pam_authenticate(pamh, 0);
       if (value == PAM_SUCCESS)
       {
          // This call is seg faulting.
          value = pam_acct_mgmt(pamh, 0);
          return value;
       }
       else
          printf("Failed on Authentication\n");
    }
  }

  pam_end(pamh, value);
  return value;
}
```

`conv` is defined as the following:

```
int nullConv(int num_msg, const struct pam_message** msg, struct pam_response** resp,
    void* appdata_ptr)
{
   *resp = reply;
   return PAM_SUCCESS;
}
static struct pam_conv conv = { nullConv, NULL };
```

This is a very simple function that works most of the time. I am working on a Linux box. When I mess with a user account, say `bob` and make his `Maximum number of days between password change` less than `Number of days of warning before password expires` by using...

`#chage -M 28 bob`

`#chage -W 29 bob`

The application seg faults at the call to `pam_acct_mgmt`.  If I change it so that the Maximum number is greater than the Number before warning, my application runs as expected.

`#chage -M 30 bob`.  Now I'm fine and the user can log in.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following post:
https://serverfault.com/questions/249671/switch-on-pam-debugging-to-syslog
and followed the accepted solution.  The results I found in my `/var/log/debug.log` file stated `pam_tally(system-auth:auth): unknown option: reset`

The line in my PAM `/etc/pam.d/system-auth` file it was referring to was a line that read

`account  required pam_tally.so reset`

When I removed the `reset` option, everything works fine.

By the way `pam_vsyslog` has a serious bug. It was segfaulting on a simple `strcmp`.